# Get System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window from WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm writing a WPF app, and I'd like to make use of [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21276/Vista-TaskDialog-Wrapper-and-Emulator).

I can get an `IntPtr` for the window by using

```
new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle
```

but that won't cast to `System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window`, which I need to show this WinForms dialog.

How do I cast `IntPtr` to  `System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**OPTION 1**

IWin32Window only expects a `Handle` property, which is not too difficult to implement since you already have the IntPtr.  [Create a wrapper](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/03/23/465.aspx) class that implements IWin32Window:

```
public class WindowWrapper : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
{
    public WindowWrapper(IntPtr handle)
    {
        _hwnd = handle;
    }

    public WindowWrapper(Window window)
    {
        _hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get { return _hwnd; }
    }

    private IntPtr _hwnd;
}
```

You would then get your IWin32Window like this:

```
IWin32Window win32Window = new WindowWrapper(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
```

or (in response to KeithS' suggestion):

```
IWin32Window win32Window = new WindowWrapper(this);
```

**OPTION 2** (thx to Scott Chamberlain's comment)

Use the existing NativeWindow class, which implements IWin32Window:

```
NativeWindow win32Parent = new NativeWindow();
win32Parent.AssignHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
```

Comment: Great answer; the class, though, might accept a Window and handle the first layer of WindowInteropHelper wrapping as well, so all you need is `new WindowWrapper(this)` and you have something to pass in as an IWin32Window.

Comment: Instead of making your own class .NET provides a similar class already in its [`NativeWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Just call [`AssignHandle(IntPtr)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.assignhandle(v=vs.110).aspx) with the handle from the function provided by the OP.

Comment: I couldn't get Option 2 to compile. My code...

`System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window win32Window = new System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow();

win32Window.AssignHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);`

...results in the compile error "IWin32Window does not contain a definition for AssignHandle".  I tried using the System.Windows.Interop version of IWin32Window but that doesn't have a NativeWindow() method.

Comment: @KarlHoaglund, thanks for catching this. `AssignHandle` is a method of NativeWindow and not IWin32Window.  You would need to cast to NativeWindow or declare `win32Window` as a NativeWindow before the AssignHandle method is available .  I'll update the answer

Comment: If we use Option2, do we need to call ReleaseHandle when we've finished? Do we need to 'clean up' in any way?

Comment: @bornfromanegg From the documentation, `To ensure proper garbage collection, handles must either be destroyed manually using DestroyHandle or released using ReleaseHandle.`