# How to use Form.Show(IWin32Window)

Tags: c#, winforms, office-addins, visio, window-handles

My goal is to use Form as progress bar of the Visio Application during some long actions. 
Which means, the Form should be display on top of the Visio Application. 
I also need the Form as non modal dialog (means not `Form.ShowDialog()`) in order to letting the Visio app to continue works while the Form is appeares.

I've already tried the following steps:

1. Create a wrapper class that implements the IWin32Window.

```
public class WindowWrapper : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
{
    public WindowWrapper(IntPtr handle)
    {
        _hwnd = handle;
    }

    public WindowWrapper(Window window)
    {
        _hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get { return _hwnd; }
    }

    private IntPtr _hwnd;
}
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296018/get-system-windows-forms-iwin32window-from-wpf-window/10296513#10296513)

2. Passing the Application.WindowHandle as the owner as follows:

```
myForm = new Form();
myForm .Show(new WindowWrapper(new IntPtr(Application.WindowHandle)));
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61756628/in-office-add-in-c-there-is-an-option-to-open-form-on-top-of-the-office-applic)

**but unfortunately,** the `Application.WindowHandle` Does not work well for a particular computer and throws some error (If necessary, i believe i can reproduce it and quote the error/exception). 
When i tried the `Application.WindowHandle32` instead of `Application.WindowHandle` there is no error, but the Form go behind the Visio Application instead of display on top of the Visio.

**Please help, how can i cause the Form to display on top of the Visio for using the Form as progress bar?** 
**Can you please do some order and explain for me the differences between the following properties of the Visio Application?**

1. Application.WindowHandle
2. Application.WindowHandle32
3. Application.InstanceHandle
4. Application.InstanceHandle32
5. Application.InstanceHandle64

Comment: Is your application a Visio add-in, or a stand-alone application?

Comment: Visio Add-in application.

Comment: Please help me..

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what could be the problem - the WindowHandle32 should "just work".